# How to access a parent style resource from within a ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, resources, controltemplate

With the following code I can access the `Tag` value of a `Style` from within a `ControlTemplate`:

```
<!-- TabItem ControlTemplate -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ctrlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    ...
    <TextDecoration.Pen>
        <Pen Brush="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Thickness="4" />
    </TextDecoration.Pen>
    ...
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- TabItem Style -->
<Style x:Key="styleTabItem" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="Gold" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ctrlTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Since the `Tag` property is already used in my case, my question is: How can I import the `Brush` from within the `ControlTemplate`
if the `Brush` is a `Style` resource?

```
<!-- TabItem Style -->
<Style x:Key="styleTabItem" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushForUnderline" Color="Gold" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ctrlTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: what about using of attached properties as the store mechanism?

Comment: Attached property for `TabItem` class? Yes, I think it's possible. But I hope, there's a simpler solution.